# Create JEE project from scratch using command lines (maven, Tomcat, spring, hibernate)

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, tomcat, command-line, maven-3

I want to create a JavaEE project that runs on tomcat. I used to do this using eclipse plugins, but now I'm using intelliJ comunity edition that does not support JEE features.

Is there any kind of tutorial or guide that explains how to build a JEE project from scratch (using command lines for eg). I tired googling this but most of the tutorial are based on eclipse plugins which is a bit sad :(

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try creating a Maven project in IntelliJ and select 'Create from archetype'. From the list you can select  the JavaEE archetype that best suites your needs

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you [jhipster](http://jhipster.github.io/).

**jhipster** is like [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) but for `javaEE`.

It pretty simple but one drawback is stack is a bit predefined. So if you won't use `spring`, `angularJS` or something else it can be difficult.